# AzureDataFactory - DataFlow - TimeStamp issue

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a source activity in data flow with **Inline data type**: 'delta' and I am trying to read only the last uploaded data, my idea is currentUTC -1 and I am using the following function:

[image: currentUTC]

And this is the error I'm getting:

[image: error]

I tried with addDays, subDays and only currentTimestamp -1 but I get this error every time.
Shouldn't I add another activity to select the latest data based on the output from the source?

Comment: Can you provide your delta table properties from databricks? like history, version?

Comment: It's about parquet files in a container that I want to combine and read, since they represent one table. The idea is not reading them 1 by 1, but to scan the files and read them at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You can see as the error suggests, the timestamp which you have given is after the last commit of the delta table. If your time stamp is greater than last commit it will give the above error.

So, the time stamp for this should be the suggested time stamp in the error or it should be before it.

> I am trying to read only the last uploaded data

To do this automatically, every time you need the **last commit time** (or) **latest version of the delta table**.

You can try the below workaround to achieve your requirement.

For this, you need to use **two kinds of dataflows**. **One dataflow will give above error and use this dataflow to get the latest version** of the delta table in pipeline and pass that to another dataflow.

So, in first dataflow give the `CurrentUTC()` in the Timestamp. Give your sink as well.

[image]

If you execute the above dataflow through pipeline, it will give the same error in the dataflow activity.

[image]

**On the failure of the dataflow activity**, use an integer type set variable activity to store the latest version from the above error message.

Use below dynamic expression for it.

```
@int(split(split(activity('Data flow1').error.message,'VERSION AS OF ')[1],'\"')[0])
```

[image]

This will give the latest version like below.

[image]

Now, in the second dataflow, create an **integer parameter** and give that in the source as `Version` of the delta table.

[image]

[image]

In the dataflow activity pass the variable to this parameter like below.

[image]

Add your desired sink to the dataflow and execute the pipeline. Now, your data will be copied like below sample data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! The configuration worked like this, the pipeline completed successfully, but there was no data in the final destination (azure sql database table). In the output I see rowsWritten: 0. It turned out that I have a delta log file from which I get the version, so the first step changed from DataFlow to Lookup activity with JSON, from which I take the 'version' output. Then I store the output from the 'Lookup' in 'Set variable' and pass it to the DataFlow.

Comment: Yeah to use only inline dataset, I have used dataflow. you can do that with lookup as well.